# DROPDOWN LIST no muestra datos de MySQL, JAVA, JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

tengo un problema al querer mostrar mis datos de mi tabla **perfil** en donde solo tengo dos datos, ADMINISTRADOR y EMPLEADO que son los nombres de perfil

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que intento hacer para mostrarlos en mi dropdown es lo siguiente:

```html
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<label>Perfil</label>
                        <select class="form-control" style="width: 250px"> 
                            <!--<option value="-1">Selecciona un perfil</option> -->
                            <% 
                                try
                                {
                                    String Query = "SELECT * FROM perfil";
                                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registrousuario","root", "");
                                    
                                    Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
                                    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(Query);
                                    while(rs.next())
                                    {  
                                        %>
                                            <option value="<%=rs.getString("nombrePerfil")%>"></option>
                                            <%=rs.getString("nombrePerfil")%>
                                        <%
                                    }
                                }
                                catch(Exception ex)
                                {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                    out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
                                }
                            %>  
                        </select>
```

pero al momento de revisarlo en mi sitio web no me aparecen los respectivos nombres de perfil, si lo despliego no me muestra nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo una clase CONEXION donde me conecto a mi base de datos, que es la siguiente

```html
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

public class Conexion 
{
    public DriverManagerDataSource Conectar()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registrousuario");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Alguna sugerencia sobre como poder mostrar los nombres de perfil o algo que este haciendo mal, se los agradecería

Comment: Siempre tienes que verificar si `rs` trae  datos:`if (!rs.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
    //Imprimir que no hay datos
} else { //leer y/o mostrar los datos  }` Ponlo así y dinos qué ocurre.

Comment: @A.Cedano al momento de poner el if (!rs.isBeforeFirst() )  y me devuelve que no hay datos, pero ya logre solventar el error, muchas gracias por tu consejo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estas imprimiendo mal en el `while`. Me parece que debe ser así:

```
while(rs.next()){  
    %>
        <option value="<%=rs.getString("idPerfil")%>"><%=rs.getString("nombrePerfil")%></option>

    <%
}
```

Aunque opino que deberias usar `jsp:usebean` con `c:forEach` para que no tengas código `java` en el `jsp` ya que eso es mala practica:

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!--......................-->
        <jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.example.ListBean" scope="page"/>

        <select>
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${obj.items}">
             <option>${item}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
```

El ejemplo completo esta [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901620/6009099).

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha funcionado de maravilla, mi problema era que antes en el while declaraba como int el idPerfil "<%=rs.getInt("idPerfil")%>"> y solo era poner getString, muchas gracias!!